# xdotool for Raspbian Stretch

Tags: apt, raspbian-stretch

I am using Raspbian Stretch with desktop 
Version: March 2018 Release date: 2018-03-13.
I wanted to install the xdotool package, unfortunately without success.

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool returns:
E: Unable to locate package xdotool
```

Is xdotool not available for Raspbian Stretch?

Comment: http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/x/xdotool/

Comment: Have you run `apt-get update` recently, @Sam? If not, try running that and check again. As Fabian says, the package definitely *exists*, so it must be an issue on your end. Have you been able to install other packages normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my raspberry pi running `Raspbian strech 2018-03-13` I find:

```
rpi3 ~$ apt list xdotool
Listing... Done
xdotool/stable 1:3.20160805.1-3 armhf
rpi3 ~$
```

So you should also find it. Be sure yo have the repository in `sources.list` and update/full-upgrade it:

```
rpi3 ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt update
rpi3 ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade

rpi3 ~$ sudo apt install xdotool
```